# How to set different colors to individual items in an SWT Combo

Tags: java, drop-down-menu, combobox, swt

I have a Combo dropdown in SWT and have been thinking of setting different colors to different items in my list based on some conditions. I'll decide later (i.e if the String has over 5 characters the item should have a red background otherwise it should be green)

I managed to change the background of the whole Combo widget but have noticed no method to change the background for its individual items.

```
Color colorGreenSWT = new Color(null, 0, 255, 0);
Combo combo = new Combo(comp, SWT.DROP_DOWN);
String[] languages = { "i", "it", "item", "items", "more_items" };
for (int i = 0; i < languages.length; i++)
    combo.add(languages[i]);
combo.setBackground(colorGreenSWT);
```

So is there any method to select the background color for each item in part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combo does not allow that. The Nebula project has a TableCombo Widget [1] that might interest you. Also SWT has an extended custom combo called CCombo that you might want to look at [2].

[1] https://eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/tablecombo/tablecombo.php

[2] http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fcustom%2FCCombo.html

Comment: The `CCombo` is a custom widget, assembled from a text widget with a button next to it and a `List` to drop down. The List does not allow for individually colored items either.

Comment: Tried the Nebula TableCombo and while it does go a long way to being what I need I still can't seem to change the background color for individual items. Still, I can add images and change text font and color, so I might just go with that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually I found it. The TableCombo object can call getTable() which you can use to define your own TableItem object which can be set independently to it's own background color.